# How do I save the game?

Tags: lego-star-wars

I just got Lego Star Wars - The Complete Saga for my son. It seems to autosave in some fashion. But it also warns me on exit that my progress will be lost since the last save. How can I save manually?

Comment: The only reason it asks to save if you exit the game is because it is possible to have picked up coins in the "level select" level.  There aren't really any "normal" autosave points there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can't be done. You can trigger an autosave by finishing a level or buying an item, though.

Comment: In addition to these, it appears that I can save during free play.  At least, it offers to let me save, though if I enter the same level again, it puts me back at the beginning.  I guess it keeps track of canisters, studs, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about it - many games that use an autosave feature give a warning like this, even if it's just saved the game. You can read it as 'make sure you hit a checkpoint before you quit, otherwise you'll lose everything you've done since the last one'.

As long as you quit after hitting a checkpoint your progress will be saved.

Comment: So in this game, what's a checkpoint?  Do I have to completely finish a level to trigger a save?

Comment: Yes, according to [this LucasArts help page](http://yodashelpdesk.lucasarts.com/faq.asp?sid=120442101223066249072013&pid=1587&pnm=LEGO%20Star%20Wars:%20The%20Complete%20Saga&seid=400001952&pos=Windows%20XP&top=All&rid=400002250) The link refers to the Windows version but I imagine the console versions are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Playing on iOS I've found a way to trigger a save in the cantina without having to purchase an item. View one of the minifigs in the cylindric water chamber, change at least one of their parts using the white arrows and exit the edit mode. This brings up the Death Star briefly in the upper right corner indicating a save is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the bar in the start of a new game and you can create a new autosave under the character option. You can visit bars within the game to save at anytime...

Answer (score 0):

For all the people who have a problem with saving the game Star Wars TCS, here's a solution which worked for me.

The problem lies not in the Xbox 360 game or Xbox One or an Xbox Live account. It lies in the hardware. It is in the WiFi router at the settings. Make connection to your WiFi router and see if cloud security is on. With me the cloud security was enabled, which should be set to disabled. Save the new settings on your WiFi router. Then you go to your Xbox One. Start the game Star Wars TCS and you will see that it automatically recognizes your user profile and starts downloading it  for your Xbox 360 game. Then, after playing each level, you can save the game. If this still does not work the stop your WiFi firewall. It must certainly succeed.